# Print a letter Fibonacci

Tags: code-golf, string, fibonacci

Given *N* (2 <= *N*), print *N* lines of the letter Fibonacci series like this (i.e. *N* = 5)
First, start with `a` and `b`:

```
a
b
```

Next, add the two lines.

```
a
b
ab
```

Keep adding the last two lines.

```
a
b
ab
bab
```

Keep going...

```
a
b
ab
bab
abbab
```

And we're done.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63127/42963)

Comment: Can it be a function which returns a list of terms up to N?

Comment: Do we have to print the result or can we return a list of strings from a function?

Comment: Wait, so it doesn't have to work for n=1?

Comment: Also, can we use 0-based indexing?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix The input isn't really an index, but the number of strings we should print.

Comment: @Dennis ahh... I misunderstood, there goes my solution :(

Comment: printing the entire sequence seems like a trivial addition to the challenge that doesn't add any substance to the questions. print element(n) would be much more desirable IMO

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, 41 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @xnor*

```python
a,b="ab";exec"print a;a,b=b,a+b;"*input()
```

[Test on Ideone](http://ideone.com/zeXj9d)

Simply follows the recursive definition.

Comment: This is shorter as a program: `a,b="ab";exec"print a;a,b=b,a+b;"*input()`.

Comment: Might want to specify python 2 :)

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>29</s> <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```
a%b=a:b%(a++b)
(`take`("a"%"b"))
```

Simple recursion.

For reference: the old version (an adaption of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86961/34531)), 
concatenated the strings in the wrong order, so I had to add a `flip(...)` which made it too long (35 bytes).

```
f="a":scanl(flip(++))"b"f
(`take`f)
```

Comment: The output is different from the example (different order in concatenation): `["b","a","ab","aba","abaab"]`

Comment: @Angs: Oops what a mistake! Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Thanks to *Emigna* for saving a byte!

```
'a='b¹GD=Š«
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=J2E9J2LCuUdEPcWgwqs&input=OQ)

Comment: `Íƒ` could just as well be `G` as you're not using `N` :)

Comment: @Emigna Oh yeah, you're right! Thanks :)!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to @Arnauld*

```js
f=(n,a="a",b="b")=>n&&f(n-!alert(a),b,a+b)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”a”bṄ;¥@¡f
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdYeKAnWLhuYQ7wqVAwqFm&input=&args=NQ)

#### How it works

```
”a”bṄ;¥@¡f  Main link. Argument: n

”a          Set the return value to 'a'.
  ”b    ¡   Call the link to the left n times, with left argument 'b' and right
            argument 'a'. After each call, the right argument is replaced with the
            left one, and the left argument with the return value. The final
            return value is yielded by the quicklink.
      ¥       Combine the two atoms to the left into a dyadic chain.
    Ṅ           Print the left argument of the chain, followed by a linefeed.
     ;          Concatenate the left and right argument of the chain.
       @      Call the chain with reversed argument order.
         f  Filter the result by presence in n. This yields an empty string
            and thus suppresses the implicit output.
```

Comment: I had the `”a”b;@Ṅ` part down, but I couldn't figure out where to go from there... now I know :-)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 7, 69 bytes

```java
String c(int n,String a,String b){return n--<1?"":a+"\n"+c(n,b,a+b);}
```

#### ungolfed

```java
 class fibb {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( c( 7, "a" , "b" ) );

}
static String c(int n,String a,String b) {
    
    return n-- < 1  ? "" : a + "\n" + c(n,b,a + b);
    
}
}
```

Comment: You really need to format your ungolfed code a bit more in your answers.. xD +1 though, and it even works for any other starting strings different than just `a` and `b`. I'm not sure if the `"a"` and `"b"` parameters should be counted towards the byte-count though, since the question specifically states it should use `a` and `b`. Not that Java will ever win anyway. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the string parameters are required because their values change each time the method is invoked.

Comment: @Snowman I know they are required.. I'm just saying that the byte-count should maybe be 75 bytes (+6 for `"a"` and `"b"`) instead of 69 because the challenge specifically asked for `a` and `b`, and the code-snipped/method currently uses a variable input. Not sure what the rules are regarding something like this, but I personally think it should be counted. Otherwise you could in some languages have a function that executes a parameter function, and then simply give the entire challenge-function in the parameter without counting its bytes. Sounds like a standard-loophole type of rule.

Comment: I love Java answers. They stand out so nice - 12 bytes here, 5 there, 17 here... 70 bytes there... wait, what? Oh, it's Java again... +1

Answer (score 5):

## Emacs, <s>26</s>, 25-ish keystrokes

#### Program

<kbd>#n</kbd> to be read as key with digit(s) *n*:

<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>UP</kbd><kbd>UP</kbd><kbd>C-SPACE</kbd><kbd>C-E</kbd><kbd>M-W</kbd><kbd>DOWN</kbd><kbd>DOWN</kbd><kbd>C-Y</kbd>
<kbd>UP</kbd><kbd>C-A</kbd><kbd>C-SPACE</kbd><kbd>C-E</kbd><kbd>M-W</kbd><kbd>DOWN</kbd><kbd>C-E</kbd><kbd>C-Y</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd><kbd>C-#(n-2)</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>

### Explanation

```
command(s)               explanation                      buffer reads (| = cursor aka point)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A<RET> B<RET>            input starting points            "a\nb\n|"
<F3>                     start new macro                  "a\nb\n|"
<UP><UP>                 move point two lines up          "|a\nb\n"
C-<SPACE> C-E M-W        copy line at point               "a|\nb\n"
<DOWN><DOWN>             move point two lines down        "a\nb\n|"
C-Y                      yank (paste)                     "a\nb\na|"
<UP>                     move point one line up           "a\nb|\na"
C-A C-<SPACE> C-E M-W    copy line at point               "a\nb|\na"
<DOWN>                   move point one line down         "a\nb|\na|"
C-E C-Y <RET>            yank (paste) and add new line    "a\nb|\nab\n|"
<F4>                     stop macro recording             "a\nb|\nab\n|"
C-#(n-3) <F4>            apply macro n-3 times            "a\nb|\nab\nbab\nabbab\n|"
```

### With n=10

```
a
b
ab
bab
abbab
bababbab
abbabbababbab
bababbababbabbababbab
abbabbababbabbababbababbabbababbab
bababbababbabbababbababbabbababbabbababbababbabbababbab
```

Comment: I'm torn. On one hand, I always upvote editor-golf, but on the other hand I use vim. Oh well, +1 anyway. :)

Comment: @DrMcMoylex just convert it to vim with C-u M-x convert-to-vim

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
'a'b{_@_n\+}ri*;;
```

explanation

```
"a": Push character literal "a" onto the stack.
"b": Push character literal "b" onto the stack.
{_@_p\+}
    {: Block begin.
    _: duplicate top element on the stack
    @: rotate top 3 elements on the stack
    _: duplicate top element on the stack
    n: print string representation
    \: swap top 2 elements on the stack
    +: add, concat
    }: Block end.
r: read token (whitespace-separated)
i: convert to integer
*: multiply, join, repeat, fold (reduce)
;: pop and discard
;: pop and discard
```

Comment: By the way, the number of strings is currently off by one; the last `p` should be a `;`. You can get rid of the quotes around the output if you use `n` instead of `p`. Finally, `'a'b` saves two bytes over `"a""b"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 18 bytes

```
ia
bkÀñyjGpgJkñdj
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=aWEKYhtrw4DDsXlqR3BnSmvDsWRq&input=&args=Nw)

Or, the more readable version:

```
ia
b<esc>kÀñyjGpgJkñdj
```

Explanation:

```
ia
b<esc>          " Insert the starting text and escape back to normal mode
k               " Move up a line
 Àñ       ñ     " Arg1 times:
   yj           "   Yank the current line and the line below
     G          "   Move to the end of the buffer
      p         "   Paste what we just yanked
       gJ       "   Join these two lines
         k      "   Move up one line
           dj   " Delete the last two lines
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 55 bytes

```python
def f(n):m='a','b';exec'print m[-2];m+=m[-2]+m[-1],;'*n
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
97c98ci2-:"yyh
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OTdjOThjaTItOiJ5eWg&input=NQ)

```
97c     % Push 'a'
98c     % Push 'b'
i2-     % Input number. Subtract 2
:"      % Repeat that many times
  yy    %   Duplicate the top two elements
  h     %   Concatenate them
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 33 bytes

```
.+
$*
^11
a¶b
+`¶(.+?)1
¶$1¶$%`$1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCoKXjExCmHCtmIKK2DCtiguKz8pMQrCtiQxwrYkJWAkMQ&input=NQ)

Saved 10 (!) bytes thanks to @[MartinEnder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)!

#### Explanation

Converts the input to unary, subtracts `2` and adds the `a` and the `b`, then recursively replaces the remaining `1`s with the concatenation of the two previous strings.

Comment: Saved a few bytes by avoiding unnecessary captures: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCoKXjExCmHCtmIKK2DCtiguKz8pMQrCtiQxwrYkJWAkMQ&input=NQ

Comment: @MartinEnder Nice! Didn't quite see the power of ``$%` ``! and that other capture was just bad planning... Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <s>102</s> 93 bytes

```
@set a=a
@set b=b
@for /l %%i in (2,1,%1)do @call:l
:l
@echo %a%
@set a=%b%&set b=%a%%b%
```

Fortunately variables are expanded for every line before assignments take effect, so I can set both `a` and `b` using their old values without needing a temporary. Edit: Saved 9 bytes thanks to @nephi12.

Comment: I was about to do this ;) By the way, you can save 8 bytes by removing the "exit/b" and starting your loop from 2: `for /l %%i in (2,1,%1) etc..`

Comment: One more (the newline) by putting the set commands on the same line `@set a=a&set b=b` like you did with the last one. though techncally they could all be on the same line... but that would be ugly... hmm...

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 45 +1 = 46 bytes

+1 byte for -n flag

```
$a=a,$b=b;say($a),($a,$b)=($b,$a.$b)for 1..$_
```

Slight improvement over the existing 49-byte solution, but developed separately.  The parentheses for `say($a)` are necessary because otherwise, it interprets `$a,($a,$b)=($b,$a.$b)` as the argument of `say` which outputs more junk than we need.

## Perl, 42 bytes

```
$b=<>;$_=a;say,y/ab/bc/,s/c/ab/g while$b--
```

A separate approach from the above solution:

```
$b=<>;                                       #Read the input into $b
      $_=a;                                  #Create the initial string 'a' stored in $_
           say                               #Print $_ on a new line
               y/ab/bc/                      #Perform a transliteration on $_ as follows:
                                   #Replace 'a' with 'b' and 'b' with 'c' everywhere in $_
                        s/c/ab/g             #Perform a replacement on $_ as follows:
                                   #Replace 'c' with 'ab' everywhere in $_
              ,        ,         while$b--   #Perform the operations separated by commas
                                   #iteratively as long as $b-- remains truthy
```

I'm not yet convinced I can't combine the transliteration and replacement into a single, shorter operation.  If I find one, I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

## Stack my Golf, 63 bytes

Get my language here: https://github.com/cheertarts/Stack-My-Golf.

```
($1=(_(a))($2=(_(b))($2-f:1-f,)?)?)f\($1=(f)($1-p(\n),:f,)?)p\p
```

There is probably a shorter way but this is the most obvious.

Answer (score 2):

## [SOML](https://github.com/dzaima/SOML), 8 bytes

```
 a b.{;t⁴+
```

explanation:

```
 a b.{;t⁴+                                        stack on 1st cycle
 a              push "a"                               ["a"]
   b            push "b"                               ["a","b"]
    .{          repeat input times                     ["a","b"]
      ;         swap the two top things on the stack   ["b","a"]
       t        output the top thing on the stack      ["b","a"]
        ⁴       copy the 2nd from top thing from stack ["b","a","b"]
         +      join them together                     ["b","ab"]
```

This language is still in development and I did add a couple new functions while writing this.

Also, 1st post on PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Great first post!

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

Includes +3 for `-n`

Give count on STDIN

```
perl -M5.010 fibo.pl <<< 5
```

`fibo.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
$_=$'.s/1//.$_,say$`for(a1.b)x$_
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, 76 Bytes

```
func f(_ n:Int,_ x:String="a",_ y:String="b"){if n>1{print(x);f(n-1,y,x+y)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 48 bytes

**47 bytes code + 1 for `-n`.**

Simple approach. Try using an array slice originally `$a[@a]="@a[-2,-1]"` but that necessitates `$"=""` or similar :(. Save 1 byte thanks to @[Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55508/dada)!

```pl
@;=(a,b);$;[@;]=$;[-2].$;[-1]for 3..$_;say for@
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -nE '@;=(a,b);$;[@;]=$;[-2].$;[-1]for 3..$_;say for@' <<< 5
a
b
ab
bab
abbab
```

Comment: You can save one byte by using `@;` instead of `@a` so you can omit the final semicolon (see what I mean?). (I know, one byte is pretty cheap but I didn't have any better idea..)

Comment: @Dada Yeah, I tried that, but it wound't compile on my machine, so I thought perhaps there's something odd going on with mine: ``perl -pe '@;=(a,b);$;[@;]=$;[-2].$;[-1]for 3..$_;say for@' <<< 5   
syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF   
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`` but didn't think it'd be fair to add as an answer if I couldn't get it working!

Comment: Sure this isn't related to the `-pe` instead of `-nE` ? Any way, it works on mine, so it's probably related to your perl version or system... But trust me, I tested it and it works! ;)

Comment: @Dada I get the same with `-nE` as well (don't know where `-pe` came from! Must be Friday...) I'll update that when I get a mo! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>63</s> 62 bytes

Recursive version:

```
function f($n,$a=a,$b=b){return$n--?"$a
".f($n,$b,$a.$b):'';}
```

Comment: unnecessary whitespace after `return`

Answer (score 1):

## **C**, 156 bytes (without indent)

```
void f(int n)
{
    char u[999]="a",v[999]="b",*a=u,*b=a+1,*c=v,*d=c+1,*e,i;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n",a);
        for(e=c;*b++=*e++;);
        e=a;a=c;c=e;e=b+1;b=d;d=e;
    }
}
```

Two buffers (u & v) store the last two lines. The newest line (tracked with two pointers: start=c, end=d) is appended to the oldest one (start=a, end=b). Swap (a,b) and (c,d), and loop. Pay attention to buffer size before requesting too much lines.
Not so short (as expected of a low-level language), but was fun to code.

Comment: You hardcoded the `5` but it should be user input

Comment: Hmm... I do not see "user input" as a requirement in the puzzle... Following the same path as Perl, Python, C++, ... answers, replace "int main()" with "void f(int n)".

Comment: `Given N (2 <= N), print N lines of the letter Fibonacci series like this (i.e. N = 5) `

Comment: Well, user input was a bad choice in term of words. I meant more like dynamic `N` and not fixed. Or the user might be somebody who uses your function/program.

Comment: I've corrected a stupid mistake about not copying the nul terminator. I've also put the function in a more readable state (one liners are funny, but not handy). To actually test this function, use this : int main(int n, char**p){f(n<2?5:atoi(p[1]));return 0;}

Comment: I don't have an interpreter on me, but I think these things should work: Remove the `void` keyword before `f`, remove the `int` keyword before `n`; remove the `char` keyword, move the declarations after the `char` keyword to somewhere before the definition of `f` and prefix the string literals with `L`. Should reduce byte count by 12.

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 15 bytes

```
'a'bVUFX,XYUYJV
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
a,b="ab"
for i in range(input()):
	print(a+b)
	a,b=b,a+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnyVYpMUmJKy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VIzOvoLREQ1PTiouzoCgzr0QjUTtJk4sTpDxJB8j@/98UAA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
a,b="ab"
exec"print(a+b);a,b=b,a+b;"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnyVYpMUmJK7UiNVmpoCgzr0QjUTtJ0xokkaQDZForaWXmFZSWaGj@/28KAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](http://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
J,\a\bjP.U=+Js>2J
```

A program that takes input of an integer and prints the result.

[Try it online!](http://pyth.tryitonline.net/#code=SixcYVxialAuVT0rSnM-Mko&input=MTA)

**How it works**

```
J,\a\bjP.U=+Js>2J  Program. Input: Q
 ,\a\b             Yield the two element list ['a', 'b']
J                  Assign to J
        .U         Reduce over [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., Q] (implicit input):
          =J+        J = J +
              >2J     the last two elements of J
             s        concatenated
       P           All of that except the last element
      j            Join on newlines
                   Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
A"ab" m=H+
~GHH
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=A%22ab%22+m%3DH%2B%0A%7EGHH&input=5&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 30 bytes.

`⎕IO` must be `1`.

```
{⎕←⍵}¨{⍵∊⍳2:⍵⌷'ab'⋄∊∇¨⍵-⌽⍳2}¨⍳
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
f@1="a";f@2="b";f@n_:=f[n-2]<>f[n-1];g=f~Array~#&
```

Defines a function `g` taking the single numerical input; returns a list of strings. Straightforward recursive implementation, using the string-joining operator `<>`.

## Mathematica, 56 bytes

```
NestList[#~StringReplace~{"a"->"b","b"->"ab"}&,"a",#-1]&
```

Unnamed function, same input/output format as above. This solution uses an alternate way to generate the strings: each string in the list is the result of simultaneously replacing, in the previous string, all occurrences of "a" with "b" and all occurrences of "b" with "ab".

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```
<?=$c=a;for($b=b;--$argv[1];$b=$c.$b,$c=$a)echo"
",$a=$b;
```

<s>come php 7.1 you can save 3 bytes by changing to:</s> an "old" version that I wish was short:

```
<?=$a=a;for($b=b;--$argv[1];[$a,$b]=[$b,$a.$b])echo"
$b";
```

If a trailing new line is acceptable then:

```
for($b=b;$argv[1]--;$a=$b,$b=$c.$b)echo$c=$a?:a,"
";
```

is only 52 bytes.

edit: 4 bytes saved (on both usable versions) thanks to Titus.

Comment: You do not have to use open tags unless there's a full program requirement :)

Comment: @chocochaos I know, but i'm using it to print the first `a` and `<?=` is shorter than `echo`. I can do better if a trailing new line is fine and will edit the answer to that effect.

Comment: save 4 bytes on your 1st version `<?=$c=a;for($b=b;--$argv[1];$b=$c.$b,$c=$a)echo"\n",$a=$b;` and 4 bytes on your 3rd version `for($b=b;$argv[1]--;$a=$b,$b=$c.$b)echo$c=$a?:a,"\n";`

Comment: @Titus thanks, that's really clever, I'll pay attention to that in the future!

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 79 Bytes

```
{println("a\nb");x=['a','b'];(it-2).times{println(y=x.sum());x[0]=x[1];x[1]=y}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++11, <s>89</s> 98 bytes

+7 bytes for *all* lines, not only the last one. +2 bytes more for `N` being the number of lines printed, not some 0-based stuff.

```c++
#include<string>
using S=std::string;S f(int n,S a="a",S b="b"){return n-1?a+"\n"+f(n-1,b,a+b):a;}
```

Usage:

```c++
f(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 53 bytes

```
for($a=b,$b=a;$argv[1]--;$a=($_=$b).$b=$a)echo$b.'
';
```

Comment: save one byte by using double quotes and putting `$b` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby (1.9+) 46 bytes

```
a,b=?a,?b;ARGV[0].to_i.times{puts a;a,b=b,a+b}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 14 bytes

(yeah, another pyth answer)

```
A<G2VQG=H+~GHH
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=A%3CG2VQG%3DH%2B~GHH&input=10&debug=1)

**Explanation**

```
A<G2              - take "ab" from the var G, dump "a" into G and "b" into H.
    VQ            - for N in range(Q)
      G           - print G
          ~GH     - like =GH but returns the previous G
         +   H    - concatenate the old G with the current H
       =H         - put that value back into H
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 16 bytes

There might be a shorter way to duplicate the top two elements of the stack in Actually, but I'm not sure what that way is. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=J2EnYizCrGAy4pWfMs6xaW9gbmE&input=NQ)

```
'a'b,¬`2╟2αio`na
```

**Ungolfing**

```
'a'b     Push "a" then "b" to the stack.
,        Explicitly take input n.
¬        Push n-2.
`...`n   Run the following function n-2 times.
  2╟2α     Push a list that repeats the top two elements of the stack twice.
  i        Flatten that list to the stack. Stack: b, a, b, a, prev_iterations
  o        Append b to the end of a. Stack: ab, b, a, prev_iterations
a        Reverse the stack so that the strings will print in the correct order.
         Implicit print all of the elements in the stack.
```

**A different approach**

This is also 16 bytes. 
[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=J2EnYizCrGDilIJva-KVlFJpYG5h&input=Mw)

```
'a'b,¬`│ok╔Ri`na
```

**Ungolfing**

The main difference is the function in the middle, so I'll only ungolf that here.

```
`...`n   Run the following function n-2 times.
  │        Duplicate the stack.
  o        Append the last item to the end of the second-to-last item.
  k╔       Uniquify the stack by wrapping the stack in a list and then calling uniquify().
  Ri       Reverse that list before returning everything to the stack
            so that the last items are at TOS again.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8 40 bytes

Same answer as @Numberknot only written as a lambda in Java 8 which makes it smaller.

```
c=(n,a,b)->n--<1?"":a+"\n"+c.f(n,b,a+b);
```

Ungolfed version:

```
interface Function
{
    String f(int n, String a, String b);
}

public class Main
{
    static Function c; //c needs to be a member or static variable in order
                       //to reference it recursively inside the lambda

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        c=(n,a,b)->n--<1?"":a+"\n"+c.f(n,b,a+b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 82 bytes

This can surely be golfed.

```
x=c("b","a");for(i in 2:scan()-2)x=c(paste0(x[2],x[1]),x);cat(rev(x[-1]),sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 142 Bytes

*Edit: only had it printing the last line out... V2:*

Golfed:

```
string L(int n){var r=new List<string>(){"a","b"};int i=3;while(i<=n){r.Add(string.Concat(r[i-3],r[i-2]));i++;}return string.Join("\r\n", r);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public string L(int n)
{
  var r = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };

  int i = 3;

  while (i <= n)
  {
    r.Add(string.Concat(r[i-3], r[i-2]));
    i++;
  }

  return string.Join("\r\n", r);
}
```

Test:

```
var printALetterFibonacci = new PrintALetterFibonacci();
Console.WriteLine(printALetterFibonacci.L(5));

a
b
ab
bab
abbab

var printALetterFibonacci = new PrintALetterFibonacci();
Console.WriteLine(printALetterFibonacci.L(7));

a
b
ab
bab
abbab
bababbab
abbabbababbab
```

Comment: This just returns the final line, you should print/output the (N-1) lines leading up to it as well.

Comment: @HaraldKorneliussen I missed that in the post, corrected now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## GNU sed, 43 Bytes

Includes +2 for `-rn`.

```
s/1/a\nb\n/
:
P
s/(.*)\n(.*\n)./\2\1\2/
t
```

Takes input in unary ([see this consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary?answertab=votes#tab-top)).

[Try it Online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=cy8xL2FcbmJcbi8KOgpQCnMvKC4qKVxuKC4qXG4pLi9cMlwxXDIvCnQ&input=MTExMTE&args=LXJu)

**Explanation:**

```
s/1/a\nb\n/              # prepend an 'a' and a 'b' on their own lines and remove a '1'
:                        # nameless label
P                        # print everything before the first newline
s/(.*)\n(.*\n)./\2\1\2/  # replace the first two lines and the next character 
                         # (one of the '1's) with the second line then the first line 
                         # concatenated with the second
                         # E.g.
                         #     a           b
                         #     b      ->   ab
                         #     11111       1111
t                        # loop to the label if there was a '1' left (i.e. there was
                         # a substitution)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell 1.0+, <strike>41</strike> 51 :( Bytes

```
$x,$y='a','b';0..(read-host)|%{$x;$x,$y=$y,($x+$y)}
```

4 *nix goto https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Corrected for user input :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This answer doesn't look like it takes input -- instead it just always prints out the first 10 results.

Comment: Hi TimmyD, thats right, but you can alter the amount of lines here :) 0..N

Comment: I did not really figure out if it is needed to ask the user for Input in the question, but I can extend it for user Input ;)

Comment: Yes, you'll need to take input via a [standard input method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). For this, something like `0..$args[0]` and having the input be a command-line parameter would probably be shortest.

Comment: Unfortunately i found only (read-host) then it would be like:

Comment: that 1..(read-host) which is too long.
except giving alias before is alowed ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `d`, \$17\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 13.99 bytes

```
'aX'bYR{xDZKyAx+Y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abRSilLsgqWlJWm6FhvVEyPUkyKDqitcorwrHSu0IyHiUOkFC00hDAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@Zä+ Ì}ha¬pb
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=QFrkKyDMfWhhrHBi&input=NQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `--`, 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'aß'bß${Ɓ+ß
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSdhJTIwcHJpbnRfd2l0aG91dF9wb3BwaW5nJTIwJ2IlMjBwcmludF93aXRob3V0X3BvcHBpbmclMjAlMjQlN0IlMjBleGVjdXRlX3dpdGhvdXRfcG9wcGluZyUyMCUyQiUyMHByaW50X3dpdGhvdXRfcG9wcGluZyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTUmZmxhZ3M9di0t)

Given `n`, prints the first `n` terms (as the challenge asks).

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 bytes

```
`abdµµ+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKxMSk1IObT20VXtJcVJyMVQUJgsA)

Prints the infinite sequence (probably not allowed).

##### Explanation

```python
'aß'bß${Ɓ+ß  # Implicit input
'aß         '# Print "a" without popping
   'bß      '# Print "b" without popping
      ${     # Repeat (input - 2) times:
        Ɓ    #  Without popping,
         +   #  concatenate the last two items
          ß  #  Print without popping
```

```python
`abdµµ+  # Full program
`abd     # Starting from ["a", "b"],
    µµ   # construct an infinite sequence
      +  # by concatenating the last two terms
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score -1):

## Javascript (ES6), 35 bytes

```
f=v=>v&&v-1?f(v-2)+f(v-1):v?'b':'a'
```

Comment: Can you make use of `'ab'[v]`?